# Cannot curl a file host through apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, curl

I am trying to download a file using curl from a machine running apache2. My site (000-default) configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/user/files/
    <Directory /home/user/files/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From another machine on the same network I do:

```
curl http://my-share/sample.text -o "test.txt"
```

I then get:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   301  100   301    0     0   4198      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4239
```

but if I cat the content of the file is contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /sample.textconfig
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at my-share Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I can ssh to the my-share debian server just fine. Why can't I access the file, is it a firewall issue?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your apache user (normally something like www-data) does not have read access to the file `/home/user/files/sample.text` or to one of the parent directories.

Having a look at the error log of apache would help you pinpoint the issue you are facing.

Comment: In the log it just says: File does not exist: /var/www/sample.text . So is the solution to give the www-data user access to the /home/user/files folder somehow?

Comment: the path /var/www/sample.text tells me that instead of your virtualhost, the default site is being used. Try adding the
 "ServerName my-share" directive to force your virtualhost to be used.

Comment: I have tried to copy the files to /var/www and change to read/write permissions. I can now access them in the browser e.g 'my-share/sample.text' but using curl (on the same client machine) still gives the "You don't have permission to access" xml file. So maybe its not an apache2 problem but instead a curl problem.

Comment: What do the logs say for the requests that you do using curl?

Answer (score 0):

```
In the log it just says: File does not exist: /var/www/sample.text . So is the solution to give the www-data user access to the /home/user/files folder somehow? –  u123 2 hours ago
```

Did I read it correctly? Apache is reading from /var/www directory and you want to serve your files from /home/user/files? You may want to recheck your Apache config if that's true.